# Как решить ошибку 'bool' object is not callable?

Tags: python, pycharm

Новичок в программировании. При создании первого тг бота появилась такая ошибка, как ее решить?

код:

```py
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('5141305306:AAE2kOKcgo26XRLgzzPZnSaoRCmPZD-p6tk')

@bot.remove_webhook()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пиветь')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

ошибка:

> File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\first.py", line 7, in 
> def start(message):
> TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

на всякий случай скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поместите код в виде текста в вопрос.

Comment: Загляните в документацию телебота